# React Client-/Server-Side Rendering Security Issue, Hide/Protect Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

i got a question about the rendering behaviour of react. Please correct me if I'm wrong, im new to React and Web Development.

Afaik the default rendering of a react SPA happens on the client side, right?

So this means the whole JSX code in the src directory will be downloaded on the first visit of the page [(see image of the Chrome WebDeveloper Tools Source Tab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQA3B.png), right?

Let's assume i would develop an admin area where only authorized users should have access to, e.g. through JWT, the JS-Code still contains information about the admin area, even if it's not rendered, a guy with the corresponding knowledge could get access to the area because all information about the admin area is already downloaded to the client computer, right?

Sure i can protect sensitive data through the api and JWT Token, but what about if i don't want the client to know about the admin area content? Is there a best practice for some kind of this case, e.g. a mix of client-side (default user content) and server-side (admin area content) rendering? What would be the best way to do this? What are the advantages and disatvantages of client-/ or server-side rendering?

Thank you &&
please be kind, as already mentioned i'm knew to React and WebDev &&
sorry for my english, i try to improve it continuously.

Comment: You might consider code-splitting and lazy loading of specific route's components. [Example](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/lazy-loading). Otherwise, I don't think there's much issue if a user can only "discover" that there are routes the app handles/renders. If you are properly using token/etc to protect any sensitive endpoints in the backend, then just knowing a frontend "page" exists doesn't do much for anyone.

Answer (score 2):

> Afaik the default rendering of a react SPA happens on the client side, right?

Not necessarily. It depends on how you set up the project.

> So this means the whole JSX code in the src directory will be downloaded on the first visit of the page

Not necessarily. e.g. see [Webpack code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/).

> Sure i can protect sensitive data through the api and JWT Token, but what about if i don't want the client to know about the admin area content?

Don't put the content in the app. Keep it in the data that is protected by your JWT.

Or make your customer facing application and your admin application *different apps* in the first place.

> What are the advantages and disatvantages of client-/ or server-side rendering?

Server-side rendering is faster on initial load, works when JS fails, and is better food for search engines.

Client-side rendering is faster on subsequent page loads.

It's not really a factor in security.